# jsfiddle jquery ajax not returning data as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsfiddle, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to a jquery ajax call on jsfiddle but am having an issue:

```
var ajax1 = function () {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: {
            name: "thomas!"
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
};

var res = ajax1();
console.log(res);
```

prints an entire deferred object to the console. It includes `responseText` which I thought perhaps is what I should try to access, but I get undefined.

```
console.log(res.responseText);
```

[I tried this once before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820632/jsfiddle-return-html-with-jquery-when) with HTML and everything seemed to work, but the JSON is failing for some reason.

Answer (score 7):

ajax returns a promise object, not the result of the ajax request. You need to register a success  callback to get the value returned by the ajax request

It should be

```
var ajax1 = function () {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/echo/json/",
        //also the format for json request is as follows
        data: {
            json: JSON.stringify({
                name: "thomas!"
            })
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
};

var res = ajax1();
res.done(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A4uJu/)

Comment: Thanks. Unrelated question but you may know. Is there some way I can make a delay in the processing. I thought I used to be able to include it in the json object. But it does not work `data: {
            json: JSON.stringify({
                name: "thomas!",
                delay: 3
            })
        }`

Comment: @thomas see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A4uJu/2/ .... delay should be passed to `data` not to `json`

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, JQuery returns a Deferred object instance.

You should therefore be calling done() on the object to get the data:

```
var res = ajax1();
res.done(function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

[$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) returns a [jqHXR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) instance (which implements the Deferred pattern). When you return this from the function you are returning the jqHXR object. This implements a done() method which is passed a callback function.

Comment: so `return $.ajax({...});` what are you really returning? Is that deferred object simply built into $.ajax so that when jQuery sees return before it, it knows to return the deferred object, or is the $.ajax object itself within the deferred object. I don't understand the syntax.